# How do you plot nonlinear differential equations in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
Dx=y
Dy=-k*y-x^3+9.8*cos(t)
inits=('x(0)=0,y(0)=0')
```

these are the differential equations that I wanted to plot.

first, I tried to solve the differential equation and then plot the graph.

```
Dsolve('Dx=y','Dy=-k*y-x^3+9.8*cos(t)', inits)
```

like this, however, there was no explicit solution for this system.

now i am stuck :(

how can you plot this system without solving the equations?

Comment: define x,y,t and use plot after

Answer (score 3):

First define the differential equation you want to solve. It needs to be a function that takes two arguments - the current time `t` and the current position `x`, and return a column vector. Instead of x and y, we'll use `x(1)` and `x(2)`.

```
k = 1;
f = @(t,x) [x(2); -k * x(2) - x(1)^3 + 9.8 * cos(t)];
```

Define the timespan you want to solve over, and the initial condition:

```
tspan = [0, 10];
xinit = [0, 0];
```

Now solve the equation numerically using `ode45`:

```
ode45(f, tspan, xinit)
```

which results in this plot:

[image]

If you want to get the values of the solution at points in time, then just ask for some output arguments:

```
[t, y] = ode45(f, tspan, xinit);
```

You can plot the phase portrait *x* against *y* by doing

```
plot(y(:,1), y(:,2)), xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), grid
```

which results in the following plot

[image]

Comment: Yoy thanks. But now, how can I get a graph of x(1) versus x(2)? However thanks a lot for helping me.