# How do I plot a nonlinear differential equation system in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, differential-equations

Actually, I am asking the same question again

Dx=y

Dy=-k*y-x^3+9.8*cos(t)

inits=('x(0)=0,y(0)=0')

these are the differential equations that I wanted to plot.

first, I tried to solve the differential equation and then plot the graph.

Dsolve('Dx=y','Dy=-k*y-x^3+9.8*cos(t)', inits)

like this, however, there was no explicit solution for this system.

now i am stuck :(

how can you plot this system without solving the equations?

Chris Taylor solved my question by plotting y vs t and x vs t graphs.

However I wanted to know the way to plot y vs x graph(is this right? I am meaning the graph with vertical axis y, and horizontal axis x)

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

Using the code from Chris Taylor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023579/how-do-you-plot-nonlinear-differential-equations-in-matlab) as below:

```
k = 1;
f = @(t,x) [x(2); -k * x(2) - x(1)^3 + 9.8 * cos(t)];
tspan = [0, 10];
xinit = [0, 0];
[t, y] = ode45(f, tspan, xinit);
```

gives you the values x and y as functions of t from 0 to 10, stored in the first and second columns of y respectively. Therefore you can plot y(x) by simply calling

```
plot(y(:,2),y(:,1));
```

Comment: @ShawnSihyunJeon While I hate to sound like I'm fishing for reputation, it is good practice on any stack exchange site to mark an answer as accepted if you feel it solved your problem. This helps let other users that might have similar questions know that you found a good solution that might also work for them. The same thing goes for Chris Taylor's excellent answer on your first question.